# Referencing .Cells (row, 0) generates error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I get an error 1004 at the line: `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 0).Text = elements(i)`.

```
Sub Mogelijkheden()
Workbooks("Model-v6-final-test_macro_2.xlsm").Sheets("Variaties").Activate
ActiveSheet.Activate

Dim elements(3) As Variant
elements(0) = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Text
elements(1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Text
elements(2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2).Text

Dim length As Integer
length = UBound(elements) - LBound(elements) + 1

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim v As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Dim row As Integer
row = 10

'Now, "print" the combinations by looping through your array
For i = 0 To length
For j = 0 To length
For k = 0 To length
For x = 0 To length
For y = 0 To length
For z = 0 To length
For c = 0 To length
For b = 0 To length
For v = 0 To length
For n = 0 To length

ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 0).Text = elements(i)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = elements(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Text = elements(k)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Text = elements(x)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Text = elements(y)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Text = elements(z)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 6).Text = elements(c)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 7).Text = elements(b)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 8).Text = elements(v)
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 9).Text = elements(n)

row = row + 1

Next n
Next v
Next b
Next c
Next z
Next y
Next x
Next k
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Cells(row, 0) is out of context. A1 = cells(1,1).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The code you posted will loop ~59,000 times

Comment: I had to create all possibilities of a series of 9 variables * 3 options, which should generate 3^options, or 19683 possibilities. I will upload the final script in a comment below to show how I finally managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the length assignment to:

`length = ubound(elements) - 1`

Also, you want:

`ActiveSheet.cells(row, 1).value = elements(i)`

You can't write to the Text property

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with this I managed to get the script working. I made some other changes as well to match the purpose (to generate 3^9th possibilities) of the script, but by changing these lines, the script ran perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 0).Text = elements(i)
```

There is no column 0 in excel. You'll have to start with column 1 and go to 10.

`.Text` is also a read-only property of a range object. Use `.Formula` instead.

Once you fix those, you'll find your loops go too high (your `Length = 4`, but it should really be `=3`, and your loop should go just 0 to 2).

**EDIT**: Even once you fix those, you'll have more problems. I won't give them all away, but suffice it to say that 3^10 = 59,049, which could create problems with smaller numeric data types.